# Как найти максимальное и минимальное значение во вложенном объекте?

Tags: javascript

```
obj={
a0:{aa:[3,9], bb:2, cc:{aaa:4,bbb:-5}},
a1:{aa:[0,8], bb:-7, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:7}},
a2:{aa:[9,-4], bb:1, cc:{aaa:-1,bbb:8}},
a3:{aa:[8,-1], bb:7, cc:{aaa:3,bbb:0}},
a4:{aa:[-4,-2], bb:-2, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:9}}
}
```

Comment: Не особо понятно какое минимальное именно нужно, где-то массив, где-то объект и где-то просто значение. Или просто минимально и максимальное значение?

Comment: Из всего объета obj нужно найти максимальное и минимальное значение.  То есть проверить значения , которые находятся в массивах, в объектах и просто как значения. Все их сравнить и найти максимальное и минимальное.

Comment: Приведите к строке, регуляркой достать все числа. Из простого массива найти числа не сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так.

```js
const data = obj={
  a0:{aa:[3,9], bb:2, cc:{aaa:4,bbb:-5}},
  a1:{aa:[0,8], bb:-7, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:7}},
  a2:{aa:[9,-4], bb:1, cc:{aaa:-1,bbb:8}},
  a3:{aa:[8,-1], bb:7, cc:{aaa:3,bbb:0}},
  a4:{aa:[-4,-2], bb:-2, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:9}}
}
        
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  var regx = numberString.match(/-?\d+/g).map(Number);
  return regx;
}

let numbers = []
for(let item in data) {
   numbers = numbers.concat(getNumbersFromString(JSON.stringify(data[item])))
}

console.log('min', Math.min( ...numbers )) // = -7
console.log('max', Math.max( ...numbers )) // = 9
```

Comment: 0 не является минимальным числом. В объекте же присутствуют отрицательные числа

Comment: Да, согласен. Обновил код